# Compiler Errors in Java Email Validation

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having trouble with email validation in JAVA (New to this) keep getting these errors and am confused as to why. I am supposed to get the persons email, check it for set standards(by my professor), then get info about a test. When I check the email I am then supposed to display the error if there is one.

Errors

```
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:29: illegal start of expression
    private static boolean validEmail(sEmail);
    ^
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:29: illegal start of expression
    private static boolean validEmail(sEmail);
            ^
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:29: ';' expected
    private static boolean validEmail(sEmail);
                  ^
3 errors
```

Code

```
public class EmailAndGrade
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Variables
        String sEmail, sError, sTest;
        int iTest;
        char cGrade;

        sEmail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email: ");


        private static boolean validEmail(sEmail);
                {
                // editing to make requirements listed
                // return email.matches("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}");
                return email.matches("[A-Z0-9]{7}+@[springfieldcollege]+\\.[edu]");
                };

        sError = "One or More Errors with the Input Email.\n" +
                 "Email is Empty.\n" +
                 "Email must be less than 30 characters.\n" +
                 "Must end in: @springfieldcollege.edu.\n" +
                 "Can only have one @.\n" +
                 "Must start with A through Z or a through z.\n" +
                 "Can not have: # $ % & ,\n ";

        sTest = JOptionPane.showInptDialog("Enter Test Grade: ");

        iTest = Integer.parseInt(sTest);

        System.exit(0);


    }

    /*
        void checkEmails()
        {
            for(String email : emailAddresses) {
            if(validEmail(email)) {
                 // it's a good email - do something good with it

            }
            else {
                 // it's a bad email - do something... bad to it? sounds dirty...
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                              sError,
                                              "Email Error - Killian O'Brien",
                                              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
    }*/



}
```

*EDIT

Alright, now I have this code

```
package com.mkyong.regex;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailAndGrade
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Variables
    String sEmail, sError, sTest;
    int iTest;
    char cGrade;

    sEmail = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your email: ");


    sError = "One or More Errors with the Input Email.\n" +
             "Email is Empty.\n" +
             "Email must be less than 30 characters.\n" +
             "Must end in: @springfieldcollege.edu.\n" +
             "Can only have one @.\n" +
             "Must start with A through Z or a through z.\n" +
             "Can not have: # $ % & ,\n ";

    sTest = JOptionPane.showInptDialog("Enter Test Grade: ");

    iTest = Integer.parseInt(sTest);

    System.exit(0);


}

public static boolean validEmail(String sEmail){
        return email.matches("[A-Z0-9]{7}+@[springfieldcollege]+\\.[edu]");
    }

public static void checkEmails(){
    for(String sEemail : emailAddresses) {
        if(validEmail(email)) {
            // it's a good email - do something good with it
        }
        else {
            // it's a bad email - do something... bad to it? sounds dirty...
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                          sError,
                                          "Email Error - Killian O'Brien",
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                 }
             }
             }
}
```

And I am now getting these

```
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method showInptDialog(java.lang.String)
location: class javax.swing.JOptionPane
        sTest = JOptionPane.showInptDialog("Enter Test Grade: ");
                           ^
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable emailAddresses
location: class com.mkyong.regex.EmailAndGrade
        for(String email : emailAddresses) {
                           ^
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable sError
location: class com.mkyong.regex.EmailAndGrade
                                              sError,
                                              ^
N:\Programming\Java\Homework\EmailAndGrade.java:63: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable email
location: class com.mkyong.regex.EmailAndGrade
        return email.matches("[A-Z0-9]{7}+@[springfieldcollege]+\\.[edu]");
               ^
4 errors
```

As I was typing this I realized that I just have a bunch of undeclared variables. Would that be correct?

Comment: you have a semi-colon after a barce  '};
'

Comment: You can't have method definition inside a method in Java. Also, there is a semi-colon after your method declaration. Check it out, and see if you can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing **method `validEmail` inside another method** `main` which is not allowed. Move your method below out of the main function (just before your last line( before the class closing brace`}`)). **Also you are using extra semicolons** at two place in the method implementation(first line end and last line end). Remove the semicolons `;`. Finally add the **argument type class (String)** in the method signature. Updated method should look like below:

```
    private static boolean validEmail(String sEmail){
      // editing to make requirements listed
      // return email.matches("[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}");
      return email.matches("[A-Z0-9]{7}+@[springfieldcollege]+\\.[edu]");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare functions inline.  Move your declaration of `validEmail()` outside of `main()`.  It's also the case that the semi-colon should be removed from the end of your method declaration.